# Selecting only modified subdocument from Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose query like this:

```
var query = Events.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': event._id,'participants._id':participant._id},{'$set': {'participants.$': participant}}, {upsert:false,new: true},function(err,result){
    if(err){
        return res.status(500).jsonp({
            error: 'Unable to update participant'
        });
    }
    console.log(result.participants[0]);
    res.jsonp(result.participants[0]);
});
```

and the query works properly modifying the participants subdocument inside Events collection.

**The problem:**

I need only the modified participant to be returned as JSON and I am not in need of the entire participants array but I am not able to achieve this since I get all the participants when I do `console.log(result.participants);`

How do I get only the modified subdocument after the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use the native JS **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method as in the following:

```
Events.findOneAndUpdate(
    { '_id': event._id, 'participants._id': participant._id },
    { '$set': { 'participants.$': participant } }, 
    { upsert: false, new: true },
    function(err, result){
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).jsonp({
                error: 'Unable to update participant'
            });
        }
        var modified = result.participants.filter(function(p){
            return p._id === participant._id
        })[0];
        console.log(modified);
        res.jsonp(modified);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is the only way (even though its inefficient looping through).